# Javascript issues when LinkedIn is banned

Tags: javascript, dom-events, linkedin-api

When I am using LinkeIin social plugin for public profile,

I am adding these two lines:

```
 <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-format="inline" data-id="37093"></script>
```

Now LinkdIn is banned so platform.linkedin.com/in.js not reachable and give error.

How to handle this?

Comment: Banned, as in the admin at your company has restricted internet traffic from accessing the linkedin.com and it's subdomains?

Comment: ya.  linkedin.com and it's subdomains are banned. Paul problem is actually when  <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script> it going to hit platform.linkedin.com/in.js and not getting. so it give script error.  is ther any way to resolve this? if you have any idea by handling this by back end(using php ) then also no problem..